# Flask SQLAlchemy .query.all() Only Returns PK

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy with Flask and when trying to return all values from my DB I'm only getting the primary key.

*models.py*

```
from app import db

class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(64))
    color = db.Column(db.String(64))
```

*routes.py*

```
from flask import render_template, url_for
from app import db
from app.models import Category

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    categories = Category.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', categories=categories)
```

When I display the value in my html file with:

```
{{ categories }}
```

I can see the ID's of each row, but nothing else.

Sample output:

```
[<Category 1>, <Category 2>]
```

When I try iterate through the values with:

```
  {% for data in categories %}
  Data 0: {{ data[0] }}<br/>
  Data 1: {{ data[1] }}<br/>
  Data 2: {{ data[2] }}<br/>
  Data 3: {{ data[3] }}<br/>
  {% endfor %}
```

All values are empty. I'm hoping its something minor that I've overlooked, any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is a `Category` object. Unless you've made that class indexable, `data[0]` will error (which jinja2 catches and replaces with nothing). Try doing something like:

```
{% for data in categories %}
    Data {{ data.id }}: {{ data.title }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```